# Google Fit - Read data using Google API Client Library for .NET

Tags: google-fit, google-client

I'm trying read data from Google Fit using the Google API Client Library for .NET. Unfortunately the Google has only documented the [syntax](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/fitness/v1/csharp/latest/annotated.html), not the semantics of the API. I've entered information such as my height and weight to my Google Fit account. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/data-types#data_types) suggests that I can read this data (such as `com.google.height`), but there's no example on how to read data using the API. I've managed to read some data, such as sessions, but trying to read datasets is more difficult. Unless I can find more information on how to use the API, I'm pretty much flailing in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

If you've been able to at least query the API, I'm going to assume that you got the Data Store aspect set up and can properly leverage the key pairing from the data store in your request similar to the following:

```
var dataSourceRequest = service.Users.DataSources.List('DATA_STORE_USER_KEY');
var dataSourceResponse = dataSourceRequest.Execute();
```

The above query should return a list of Data Sources that are associated from that user's account.  Basically, any device that creates any type of data will have one listing in this response for each type of data that it tracks.

i.e. A scale that tracks weight and pulse would have two entries, one for weight, one for pulse.

In order to get data specific to that data source, you'll need to leverage the Source Id from one of the records in the above response (DataStreamId attribute on the object) in the following:

```
var dataSetRequest = service.Users.DataSources.Get('DATA_STORE_USER_KEY', 'SOURCE_DATA_STREAM_ID');
var dataSetResponse = dataSetRequest.Execute();
```

The above response should return a list of Google.Apis.Fitness.v1.Data.Dataset objects representing readings from that device.

From everything I've been able to find right now, the Google Fitness REST API is only able to provide data-source specific collection of data points (i.e. all weight measures from one specific scale). I've yet to figure out how to simply request all of the weight data from a User's account without restricting it to a data source of some type.